# Confusion about signature of a module in Ocaml

Tags: interface, module, ocaml, signature

Is there any difference between these two ?

I don't know which of them should I put in my `.mli` file

```
module Comparable : sig 
    type t
    val compare : t -> t-> int
end

module type Comparable = sig
    type t
    val compare : t -> t-> int
end
```

In `real world ocaml` book, the authors say that the words *interface, signature, module type* can be used interchangeably.

**PS**:I would gladly change the question title to a better suited one, any proposals ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
module type Comparable = sig
  type t
  val compare : t -> t-> int
end
```

defines a module type. Inside an interface (e.g. a `.mli` file), it is a promise that the implementation (the `.ml`) contains the same module type definition.

```
module Comparable : sig 
    type t
    val compare : t -> t-> int
end
```

in an interface is a promise to provide a module of that same type. It would be equivalent to

```
module Comparable : Comparable
```

(assuming the module type is indeed defined). It states that the corresponding `.ml` contains a *submodule* named `Comparable`.

Which of the two you should put in you `.mli` depends on what promises you want to make. Both have their uses.

Module type definitions are commonly found in interfaces if they are needed as arguments to functors. Indeed your module type `Comparable` is equal to `Map.OrderedType`, the type of the argument of the functor `Map.Make`.

One use case of submodules as above is to *provide* something that can be used as an argument to a functor. For example a `.mli` could look like this:

```
type stuff = ...
val fancy : ... (* some operations on stuff *)

module Comparable : Comparable with type t=stuff
```

In this form it would make the type `stuff` usable as the key type of a map.

That said, if your example is the complete real world example, then I suspect you want the module type definition, not the submodule: The submodule would not be very useful; you have no operation to construct anything of type `t`.

Comment: Is there a way promise that you provide a submodule type and automatically deriving that module interface from the implementation in the submodule?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: I am not entirely sure what you are asking. Maybe it is better if you make an actual question out of it. In the short of what fits into a comment: Promising to provide a module type `B` can be done like this: `module type A = sig module type B end`. Deriving a module type is done like this: `module type A_type = module type of A_implementation`.

Answer (score 2):

Your first code fragment defines a module with a specific signature
, the second one defines directly a signature not a module. 
To understand the difference, your code example may be rewriten to

```
module type COMPARABLE = sig 
   type t
   val compare : t -> t-> int
end

module Comparable: COMPARABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Say your file is named `m.mli`. The first definition is what you use if your corresponding `m.ml` file has a module `Comparable` in it. The second is what you use to declare a module type (just the type of a module, not a module). In the first case, there is an actual `compare` that can be called as `M.Comparable.compare`. In the second case there's no compare function, just a type declaration.

It's not possible to know which is correct for you. They both make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`.mli` file allows to constraint a `.ml` file, see the example below :

```
   /* foo.ml */
   let foo1 x y = x + y
   let foo  = foo1

   /* foo.mli */
   val foo : int -> int -> int

   /* main.ml */
   open Foo
   let r = foo 4 5
   /* let r = foo1 4 5 ;; */
```

`ocamlbuild main.native` will compile only when using `foo` and will fail to compiler with `foo1`.

Now, when you define a module, you can either hide some declaration when defining this module :

```
   module Comparable : sig 
   /* the exposed interface */
   end = struct 
   /* the computation */ 
   end
```

Or, define a type for a module :

```
   module type Comparable = sig 
   /* the exposed interface */
   end
```

You will be able to use that type later in your code to constraint some module. 
With the example given above (!! delete the .mli file !!)

```
   /* foo.ml */
   let foo1 x y = x + y
   let foo  = foo1

   /* main.ml */
   module type T1 = sig 
   val foo : int -> int -> int
   end

   module F1 : T1 = Foo
   let r = Foo.foo1 4 5 
   let r = F1.foo1 4 5 /* will fail because hiden by type T1 */
```